# El estado de redux no cambia en el store. CRUD con react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

Los pongo en contexto. Estoy haciendo un CRUD y el presionar al boton de editar toda la fila seleccionada se activa en el store de redux en el campo "active", entonces se abre un modal con los datos cargados que quiero editar. Hasta aqui todo bien, el problema es que cuando cierro el modal disparo una accion para regresar el campo "active" a **null**, asi en caso de seleccionar otra fila a editar se posicionara correctamente.

Bueno el problema es que cuando cierro el modal el campo "active" no esta regresando a su estado inicial el cual es **null**. Realmente no se que puede estar ocasionandolo, segun tengo entendido estoy disparando correctamente la accion. Espero me puedan ayudar gracias por adelantado!!

**Archivo de types.js**

```
export const types = {

    uiEventSetActive: '[data] Evento seleccionado', // Setea la fila seleccionada en el active
    agregarProducto: '[data] Agregar producto', // Agrega un producto 
    eventClearEvent: '[data] Limpiar el evento activo', // Limpia el campo active
}
```

**Aqui disparo la accion en un archivo data.js**

```
// Agrega un producto
export const agregar = ( usuario ) => ({

    type: types.agregarProducto,
    payload: usuario

});

// Posiciona el producto en el campo active
export const productoSeleccionado = ( usuario ) => ({

    type: types.uiEventSetActive,
    payload: usuario

});

// Limpia el campo de active
export const clearEvent = () => ({ type: types.eventClearEvent });
```

**Aqui el reducer**

```
import { types } from '../types/types';


const initialState = {
    body: [{
        id: 1,
        nombre: "andres",
        precio: "100",
        stock: "100",
        proveedor: 3,
        ID: 2
    }],
    active: null
}

export const coffeReducer = ( state = initialState, action ) => {

    switch ( action.type ) {

        // Agrega un producto
        case types.agregarProducto:
            return {
                ...state,
                body: [
                    ...state.body,
                    action.payload
                ]
            }

        // Setea el objeto en el campo active
        case types.uiEventSetActive:
            return {
                ...state,
                active: action.payload
            }

        // active deberia regresar a null
        case types.clearEvent: 
        return {
            ...state,
            active: null
        }
    
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**Y el evento para limpiar lo llamo en el archivo del modal**

```
// Cerramos el modal
const closeModal = () => {
    dispatch( uiCloseModal() );   
    dispatch( clearEvent() );
    setFormValues( initEvent );
}
```

**Adjunto imagen de como es que el active no regresa a null luego de disparar en el evento de clear active**

[image: Active se queda con el objeto]

Hay algo que este dejando pasar? :/

Gracias de antemano por tomarse el tiempo!!

Answer (score 1):

Bueno luego de echarle un ojo por milesima vez me di cuenta de que en el reducer estaba llamando a la constante:

```
clearEvent
```

La cual cree en el data.js envez de llamar al type

```
eventClearEvent
```